# How do i aggregate mongodb results as a matrix?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am trying to list the results of plays and total monies for albums in the quarter. I have managed to make it getting the data for the albums in each month of a quarter (ex.: Q1), but i am thinking if there is a solution query based in mongodb.

This is a sample data:

```
{
        "owner": "Pelé MilFlows",
        "owner_id": ObjectId("5e0e25fc3ed15e27c5f5bb2b"),
        "units": NumberInt(19802),
        "percent": 0.35,
        "value": 30.35063004976345,
        "artist_name": "Altamira",
        "release_title": "Carol",
        "upc": "3615937741130",
        "track_title": "Carol",
        "isrc": "BR9Z21900056",
        "store_name": "Spotify",
        "country": "Brazil",
        "label_name": "Altamira Music",
        "distributor": "Believe",
        "sale_type": "audio",
        "sales_id": ObjectId("5e5e91ac238279bd2ba7e839"),
        "created_at": ISODate("2020-03-11T20:18:11.076-03:00"),
        "report_name": "202002-believe.csv",
        "sales_date": ISODate("2019-11-01T21:00:00.000-03:00"),
        "distributor_date": ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00.000-02:00"),
        "distributor_value": 5.355993538193549,
    }
```

Today i am returning a result for each album / store for the month aggregating units and the money value ordered by `release_title: 1` and `total:-1` so i can list albums and each store. This data is for one month.

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "release_title": "Carol",
      "store_name": "Spotify"
    },
    "total_units": 17107,
    "total": 30.918913876318648
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "release_title": "Carol",
      "store_name": "YouTube"
    },
    "total_units": 30913,
    "total": 21.210088280499996
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "release_title": "Carol",
      "store_name": "YouTube Premium"
    },
    "total_units": 534,
    "total": 5.555646942999999
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "release_title": "Carol",
      "store_name": "Deezer"
    },
    "total_units": 1449,
    "total": 2.600975890146269
  }
]
```

And this is the query i am using to get this data:

```
                query.push({
                    $group: {
                        _id: {
                            "release_title": "$release_title",
                            "store_name": "$store_name",
                        },
                        total_units: { $sum: "$units" },
                        total: { $sum: "$value" },
                    }
                })
                query.push({ $sort: { '_id.release_title': 1,  "total": -1} })
```

To accomplish this i have to get data for the 3 months in the quarter and merge them to be something like this:

```
[
  {
    "Carol": {
      "Spotify": {
        "jan": {
          "total_units": 17107,
          "total": 30.918913876318648
        },
        "fev": {
          "total_units": 268251,
          "total": 50.6325120791936
        },
        "mar": {
          "total_units": 254012,
          "total": 47.068955094336
        }
      },
      "YouTube": {
        "jan": {
          "total_units": 30913,
          "total": 147.57352409184006
        },
        "fev": {
          "total_units": 4433,
          "total": 31.794040319219206
        },
        "mar": {
          "total_units": 0,
          "total": 0
        }
      },
      "Deezer": {
        "jan": {
          "total_units": 1449,
          "total": 2.600975890146269
        },
        "fev": {
          "total_units": 24591,
          "total": 26.4439168821248
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I tried using `$facet` and aggregate pipelines without success. Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Comment: It's not clear how do you build such object... Where "Hong Kong" comes from? How do you calculate "jan", "fev", ... ? total_units + total doesn't match from given sample and expected result... Please provide reproducible example

Comment: Hi @Valijon thanks for your reply. I have added a sample distribution data and corrected the result to meet the data i am generating. Feel free to ask for more details and/or suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that you're going to need to do multiple `$group` steps and then use `$arrayToObject` with `$map` to shape the data into the object structure you need.

Also converting dates to month strings requires a hack to map month numbers to the strings you want. I used switch but I've also seen people use `$arrayElemAt`.

Below is some sample data and the following output:

```
var a = db.test.deleteMany({})
var b = db.test.insertMany([
{
  "owner": "Pelé MilFlows",
  "owner_id": ObjectId("5e0e25fc3ed15e27c5f5bb2b"),
  "units": NumberInt(19802),
  "percent": 0.35,
  "value": 30.35063004976345,
  "artist_name": "Altamira",
  "release_title": "Carol",
  "upc": "3615937741130",
  "track_title": "Carol",
  "isrc": "BR9Z21900056",
  "store_name": "Spotify",
  "country": "Brazil",
  "label_name": "Altamira Music",
  "distributor": "Believe",
  "sale_type": "audio",
  "sales_id": ObjectId("5e5e91ac238279bd2ba7e839"),
  "created_at": ISODate("2020-03-11T20:18:11.076-03:00"),
  "report_name": "202002-believe.csv",
  "sales_date": ISODate("2019-11-01T21:00:00.000-03:00"),
  "distributor_date": ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00.000-02:00"),
  "distributor_value": 5.355993538193549,
},{
  "owner": "Pelé MilFlows",
  "owner_id": ObjectId("5e0e25fc3ed15e27c5f5bb2b"),
  "units": NumberInt(123456),
  "percent": 0.35,
  "value": 21.35063004976345,
  "artist_name": "Altamira",
  "release_title": "Carol",
  "upc": "3615937741130",
  "track_title": "Carol",
  "isrc": "BR9Z21900056",
  "store_name": "Spotify",
  "country": "Brazil",
  "label_name": "Altamira Music",
  "distributor": "Believe",
  "sale_type": "audio",
  "sales_id": ObjectId("5e5e91ac238279bd2ba7e839"),
  "created_at": ISODate("2020-03-11T20:18:11.076-03:00"),
  "report_name": "202002-believe.csv",
  "sales_date": ISODate("2019-10-01T21:00:00.000-03:00"),
  "distributor_date": ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00.000-02:00"),
  "distributor_value": 5.355993538193549,
},
{
  "owner": "Pelé MilFlows",
  "owner_id": ObjectId("5e0e25fc3ed15e27c5f5bb2b"),
  "units": NumberInt(12345),
  "percent": 0.35,
  "value": 17.35063004976345,
  "artist_name": "Altamira",
  "release_title": "Carol",
  "upc": "3615937741130",
  "track_title": "Carol",
  "isrc": "BR9Z21900056",
  "store_name": "YouTube",
  "country": "Brazil",
  "label_name": "Altamira Music",
  "distributor": "Believe",
  "sale_type": "audio",
  "sales_id": ObjectId("5e5e91ac238279bd2ba7e839"),
  "created_at": ISODate("2020-03-11T20:18:11.076-03:00"),
  "report_name": "202002-believe.csv",
  "sales_date": ISODate("2019-10-01T21:00:00.000-03:00"),
  "distributor_date": ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00.000-02:00"),
  "distributor_value": 5.355993538193549,
}
])

db.test.aggregate([
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      "release_title": "$release_title",
      "store_name": "$store_name",
      "month": { $month: "$sales_date" }, // or whichever date is appropriate
    },
    total_units: { $sum: "$units" },
    total: { $sum: "$value" },
  }
},
{
  $sort: {
    "_id.release_title": 1,
    "total": -1
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: { release_title: "$_id.release_title", store_name: "$_id.store_name" },
    value: {
      $push: {
        month: "$_id.month",
        value: {
          total_units: "$total_units",
          total: "$total"
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id.release_title",
    value: {
      $push: {
        store_name: "$_id.store_name",
        value: "$value"
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    value: [
      {
        k: "$_id",
        v: {
          $arrayToObject: {
            $map: {
              input: "$value",
              as: "value",
              in: {
                k: "$$value.store_name",
                v: {
                  $arrayToObject: {
                    $map: {
                      input: "$$value.value",
                      as: "value",
                      in: {
                        k: {
                          $switch: {
                            branches: [
                              { case: { $eq: ["$$value.month", 10] }, then: "Oct" },
                              { case: { $eq: ["$$value.month", 11] }, then: "Nov" },
                              // ...
                            ],
                            default: "Unk"
                          }
                        },
                        v: "$$value.value"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    value: { $arrayToObject: "$value" }
  }
},
{
  $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$value" }
}
])
```

Which produces the output:

```
{
  "Carol" : {
    "YouTube" : {
      "Oct" : {
        "total_units" : 12345,
        "total" : 17.3506300497634
      }
    },
    "Spotify" : {
      "Nov" : {
        "total_units" : 19802,
        "total" : 30.3506300497634
      },
      "Oct" : {
        "total_units" : 123456,
        "total" : 21.3506300497634
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @justin.m.chase, i have tested your solution and got this error: 
`
{
 "message" : "$arrayToObject requires an object with keys 'k' and 'v', where the value of 'k' must be of type string. Found type: null",
 "ok" : 0,
 "code" : 40394,
 "codeName" : "Location40394",
 "name" : "MongoError"
}
`

Comment: One of the fields must have null values, you'll probably need to filter those out with matches or set them to default values.

Comment: Comment out the last 3 steps and see how it looks after the second group. If release title or store_name are null in any data it will cause that.

Comment: i made it work adding the $match filter in the start of the pipe. I already use it for this calculation, because there are sales that are for videos and they don't have release_title. I cannot edit your answer to add it because it is saying that "Suggested edit queue is full", so, please, add it and the comments so others know that there is a catch. Thank you.

```{
    $match: {
        'release_title': {$nin: [null, false, '']},
        'distributor_date': {
            $gte: new Date('2020-01-01'),
            $lt: new Date('2020-04-01')
        }
    }
},
```